# Laravel Eloquent use where on with data specific field

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, relation

Here my code :

```
$course = Course::where('id', $activeCourseId)
        ->with(["blocks.cards" => function($q) use($cardsDueIds) {
            $q->whereNotIn('blocks.cards.id', $cardsDueIds);
            $q->take(50);
        },
        "cards",
        "blocks.cards.contexts",
        "blocks.cards.user_contexts",
        "blocks.cards.block.course",
        "blocks.cards.thisUser"])
        ->first();
```

I try to get only `block.cards` where each `block.cards[’id']` is not in `$cardsDueIds`.

Actually i have this error "

> Unknown column 'blocks.cards.id' in 'where clause'

".

Anyone know how to do this correctly ? Thanks !

Comment: `$q->whereNotIn('blocks.cards.id', $cardsDueIds);` to `$q->whereNotIn('id', $cardsDueIds);` as you r already in that relationship call back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$q->whereNotIn('blocks.cards.id', $cardsDueIds);
```

to

```php
 $q->whereNotIn('id', $cardsDueIds);
```

as you r already in that relationship call back

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$course = Course::where('id', $activeCourseId)
          ->with(["blocks.cards" => function($q) use($cardsDueIds) {
               $q->whereNotIn('id', $cardsDueIds);
        }])
        ->first();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, infortunately i have an "Undefined contexts" error.

Comment: Is the context field in the cards table?

Comment: No it's a relation

Comment: you are already in that relationship, so you can directly access the cards table field. I have updated code you can check.

Comment: Sorry the whereNotIn does not work, it works only if i remove the "->take(50)"